# Which data types in postgres do not support BETWEEN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

It seems that postgres has some real neat comparison operators on nested data types, such as:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,0] < ARRAY[1,1]
# true
```

However, I'm curious which data types support equality comparisons, but do not support collating (or is it something else?) in order to be able to use the `BETWEEN` operator. For example:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,1] BETWEEN ARRAY[1,0] < ARRAY[1,2]
# ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
```

Or is there a place I can find this in the documentation?

Comment: You can create your own operators, so everything that is not documented, can still be created. It mostly depends on your creativity and available time. For the rest, just check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html

Comment: xml and json spring to mind.  (but not jsonb, that is orderable)

Comment: I think you got the syntax wrong, this works fine: `SELECT ARRAY[1,1] BETWEEN ARRAY[1,0] AND ARRAY[1,2];`

Comment: @BlueStar oh of course, thanks for pointing that out, that was the issue !